# jQuery scrollIntoView scroll more px

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, iframe, cross-domain

Would there be any chance that I can use scrollIntoView with 100 pixel than its target element

```
document.getElementById("container").scrollIntoView(true);
```

This is to scroll to top of iframe element, for cross-domain issue that not able to select element outside iframe. Appreciate if could suggest any other solution to fix this, please?

```
<html>
<body>
<header><h1>Test Header</h1></header>
<div id="container">
 Test text
</div>
<iframe>
<button>click to top of the parent body</button>
<iframe>
```

I have tried `document.getElementById("container").scrollTop += 200;` not working for me.

Comment: i've seen, nothing to indicate, that it can be done https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Comment: I have tried, it seems stopped on  the height of iframe, can't go any further than header

Comment: please put a any test page

Comment: it needs two different domain, I am afraid that not able to do it with text page